# How can I get Ubuntu to run properly using Core i7 integrated graphics?

Tags: drivers, intel, cpu, nvidia-prime

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 on a Dell XPS 15. By default, the active graphics processor is the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2. As a result of the heat it produces(40+ °C), my computer will often spin its fans at an audible level during ordinary internet browsing. I tried using PRIME to run the i7's integrated graphics("Power Saving Mode"), only to have my computer blackscreen after I logged out and attempted to log back in. I managed to reboot into recovery mode, in which integrated graphics ran "successfully," but still left the launcher bar dark and mostly opaque. Is it possible yet for Ubuntu 17.04 to properly use integrated graphics on a Kaby Lake Core i7?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. All you need to do is to install the recommended Nvidia drivers - you don't mention it so I assume you didn't - and then select the card to use with Nvidia X Server settings and reboot, not just log out.

Comment: I installed the recommended drivers for the Nvidia card, and Nvidia X Server settings told me to log out - rebooting immediately afterwards had the same effect.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966913/boot-with-nvidia-or-intel-driver-loaded/971304#971304 Hope it helps!